# Problem with spin in synchronization not appearing with loading background image

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, backend

```js
function hideLoadingAnimation() {
  console.log("Yükleme animasyonu gizleniyor, ana içerik gösteriliyor");
  var loadingAnimation = document.getElementById("loading-animation");
  var mainContent = document.getElementById("main-content");
  loadingAnimation.style.display = "none";
  mainContent.style.display = "block";
}
window.onload = function() {
  console.log("Sayfa tamamen yüklendi");
  hideLoadingAnimation();
};
```

```css
#main-content {
  display: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  background: radial-gradient(circle, rgba(7, 50, 22, 255) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 255) 100%);
  animation: shine 4s linear infinite;
  color: white;
  font-family: "Lato";
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  max-width: 800px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.card {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: calc(33.33% - 30px + 9.999px);
  height: 340px;
  margin: 0 30px 30px 0;
  perspective: 1000;
}

.card:first-child .card__front {
  background: #5271C2;
}

.card__front img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.card:first-child .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(52, 78, 147, 0.8)
}

.card:nth-child(2) .card__front {
  background: #35a541;
}

.card:nth-child(2) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(34, 107, 42, 0.8);
}

.card:nth-child(3) {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.card:nth-child(3) .card__front {
  background: #bdb235;
}

.card:nth-child(3) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(129, 122, 36, 0.8);
}

.card:nth-child(4) .card__front {
  background: #db6623;
}

.card:nth-child(4) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(153, 71, 24, 0.8);
}

.card:nth-child(5) .card__front {
  background: #3e5eb3;
}

.card:nth-child(5) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(42, 64, 122, 0.8);
}

.card:nth-child(6) .card__front {
  background: #aa9e5c;
}

.card:nth-child(6) .card__num {
  text-shadow: 1px 1px rgba(122, 113, 64, 0.8);
}

.card:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.card__flipper {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.6s cubic-bezier(0.23, 1, 0.32, 1);
  border: 3.5px solid rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.6);
  
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.5), transparent, rgba(255, 215, 0, 0.5));
 
}

.card__front,
.card__back {
  position: absolute;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 340px;
}

.card__front {
  transform: rotateY(0);
  z-index: 2;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card__back {
  transform: rotateY(180deg) scale(1.1);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #483D8B, #301934, #483D8B, #301934);
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.card__back span {
  font-weight: bold;
 
  color: white;
  /* Beyaz renk */
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.card__name {
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 0.9;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.card__name span {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.card__num {
  font-size: 100px;
  margin: 0 8px 0 0;
  font-weight: 700;
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .card__num {
    font-size: 70px;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .card {
    width: 100%;
    height: 290px;
    margin-right: 0;
    float: none;
  }
  .card .card__front,
  .card .card__back {
    height: 290px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}


/* Demo */

main {
  text-align: center;
}

main h1,
main p {
  margin: 0 0 12px 0;
}

main h1 {
  margin-top: 12px;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.fa-github {
  color: white;
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-top: 8px;
 
}

.tm-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  

}

.tm-letter {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: translateY(0);
  animation: letter-animation 6s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes letter-animation {
  0%,
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  10%,
  40%,
  60%,
  90% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
  }
  20%,
  80% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

#m-letter {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0px;
}

a::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;

  left: 50%;
 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  
  width: 50px;
  height: 45px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px 4px rgba(110, 110, 110, 0.8);
  
  filter: blur(4px) brightness(1.5);
 
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease;
  z-index: -1;
}

a:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
}

body.hoverEffect {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at center, #000000, #000033, #000066, #1a1a1a);
}

#gameCard {
  width: 300px;
  height: 450px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 50px 10px #FFD700, /* Altın sarısı glow */
  0 0 100px 20px #0000FF, /* Mavi glow */
  0 0 150px 30px #000033;
  
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
 
  color: #FFD700;
 
  text-align: center;
  border: 3px solid #FFD700;
 
}

#gameCardLink span {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-right: 5px;
 
  font-weight: bold;

}

#gameCardLink span:last-child {
  font-size: 0.79em;
 
  vertical-align: super;
 
  opacity: 0.9;
  font-weight: bold;
  /* Metni kalın yapar */
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /* Siyah gölge ekler */
}

#loading-animation {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://www.hdwallpapers.in/download/black_hole-1920x1080.jpg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.loader {
  border-top: 9px solid #00a2ed;
  border-radius: 80%;
  width: 18vw;
  /* Genişliği viewport'un %25'i yapar */
  height: 18vw;
 
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  
  position: absolute;
 
  left: 41%;
 
  top: 38%;
 
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
 
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <html>

  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.0/p5.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css">
    <title>Game Cards App</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/entertainment-events-hobbies/24/card-game-cards-hold-512.png">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="loading-animation">
      <div class="loader"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="main-content">

      <div class="tm-container">
        <div class="tm-letter" id="t-letter">T</div>
        <div class="tm-letter" id="m-letter">M</div>
      </div>


      <audio id="flipSound" preload="auto">
  <source src="https://cdn.freesound.org/previews/321/321114_2776777-lq.ogg" type="audio/wav">
</audio>



      <main>
        <div id="gameCardLink">
          <span>G</span>
          <span>a</span>
          <span>m</span>
          <span>e</span>
          <span> </span>
         
          <span> </span>
          <span>C</span>
          <span> </span>
          <span>a</span>
          <span> </span>
          <span>r</span>
          <span> </span>
          <span>d</span>
          <span> </span>
          <span>s</span>
          <span>®</span>
         
        </div>
        <p><a href="https://github.com/murattasci06"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a></p>
      </main>


      <ul>
        <li class="card">
          <div class="card__flipper">
            <div class="card__front">
              <img src="https://gecbunlari.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/12/Spiderman-No-Way-Home.jpg" alt="Spiderman">
              <p class="card__name"><span>Marvel</span><br>Spiderman</p>
              <p class="card__num">1</p>
            </div>


            <iframe class="frame" width="225" height="340" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/JfVOs4VSpmA?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
              allowfullscreen></iframe>


            <div class="card__back">
              <svg height="180" width="180">
        <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#514d9b" stroke-width="35"  />
        <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
         <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
              <span>1.89 Bil. $</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>


        <li class="card">
          <div class="card__flipper">
            <div class="card__front">
              <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/1e/f1/3d/1ef13dfa4b7b8c131302e242d1ec48d7.jpg" alt="Batman">
              <p class="card__name"><span>DC</span><br>Batman</p>
              <p class="card__num">2</p>
            </div>

            <iframe class="frame" width="225" height="340" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mqqft2x_Aa4?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
              allowfullscreen></iframe>


            <div class="card__back">
              <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#35a541" stroke-width="35"/>
 <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
              <span>771 Mil. $</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="card">
          <div class="card__flipper">
            <div class="card__front">
              <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp12279011.jpg" alt="Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_Vol_3">
              <p class="card__name"><span>Marvel</span><br>Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_Vol_3</p>
              <p class="card__num">3</p>
            </div>
            <iframe class="frame" width="225" height="340" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/u3V5KDHRQvk?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
              allowfullscreen></iframe>


            <div class="card__back">
              <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#bdb235" stroke-width="35"/>
<!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
              <span>845.4 Mil. $</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>


        <li class="card">
          <div class="card__flipper">
            <div class="card__front">
              <img src="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/8940499.jpg" alt="Shazam">
              <p class="card__name"><span>DC</span><br>Shazam2</p>
              <p class="card__num">4</p>
            </div>
            <iframe class="frame" width="225" height="340" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/AIc671o9yCI?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
              allowfullscreen></iframe>



            <div class="card__back">
              <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#db6623" stroke-width="35"/>
<!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
              <span>462.5 Mil. $</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="card">
          <div class="card__flipper">
            <div class="card__front">
              <img src="https://images2.alphacoders.com/131/1316679.jpeg" alt="Flash">
              <p class="card__name"><span>DC</span><br>Flash</p>
              <p class="card__num">5</p>
            </div>
            <iframe class="frame" width="225" height="340" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hebWYacbdvc?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
              allowfullscreen></iframe>



            <div class="card__back">
              <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#3e5eb3" stroke-width="35"/>
 <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
              <span>560.2 Mil. $</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>

        <li class="card">
          <div class="card__flipper">
            <div class="card__front">
              <img src=" https://images3.alphacoders.com/121/1213553.jpg" alt="Dr_Strange_2">
              <p class="card__name"><span>Marvel</span><br>Dr_Strange_2</p>
              <p class="card__num">6</p>
            </div>
            <iframe class="frame" width="225" height="340" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/aWzlQ2N6qqg?autoplay=1&mute=1&vq=hd1080" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture; web-share"
              allowfullscreen></iframe>


            <div class="card__back">
              <svg height="180" width="180">
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="65" stroke="#aa9e5c" stroke-width="35"/>
 <!-- Dış dairenin kenarı (yeşil) -->
          <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="83" fill="none" stroke="rgba(7, 50, 22, 255)" stroke-width="1" />
        </svg>
              <span>955.8 Mil. $</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>

  </body>

  </html>
```

**The link icluding full code:** https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wOhvYSmlcsi5r8m4vosOMFw8Ik2ZoWsW/view?usp=sharing

Hello friends, while the page is loading, I normally expect the spin and background space-themed image to appear on the screen at the same time, but first the green background of the page that will be seen when it loads, then the spin and then the loading screen wallpaper. Is it because I downloaded the wallpaper with background-image in the loading-animation section of the style section, so I can't make them appear at the same time? But how will I ensure it?

The second thing I don't understand is I block the main-content in the style at startup, how does the background green theme color appear at startup? My expectation is that only the loading screen, wallpaper and spin will appear.

Comment: That's the problem with loading the image `https://www.hdwallpapers.in/download/black_hole-1920x1080.jpg` ... it takes actual time to load

Comment: oh, and the the green is on your body is it not?

Comment: There is a green background in the body but <style> #main-content { display:none; It should be hidden while the page is loading with

Comment: no, the body is not hidden - `#main-content` is, but it's NOT the body

Comment: You have not pasted your entire HTML. Can you edit your question and post the entirety of your HTML, preferrably as a snippet? That would help us a lot in testing your code. Thanks!

Comment: @Lajos Arpad I shared the link containing the entire code in the issue so you can test it.

Comment: Thanks, Murat. Apparently we have an accepted answer, so it seems the issue is resolved by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One potential solution to your problem is to convert the background image to Base64 code and insert it into your CSS code.

You can use a lot of tools for conversion, in the most cases I used [this online tool](https://www.base64-image.de/).

Usage:

1. Download the image file.
2. Upload it on this site
3. In the *Encoding* section you can see the results. Click on *copy css* button.
4. Insert this in your CSS file in the following format: `background-image: <copied-code>`. The result looks like this `background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,<a-very-long-hexadecimal-string>')`

Comment: Thank you for your answers, it was very informative and useful. If you are interested https://l24.im/8xFueW
You can look at this issue. @adampweb

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see the loading image taking time to appear is simply because it needs to load.

The image is not that big, roughly 200Ko but the service providing the image is slow. On my office fiber, it takes one second to load. I suggest you try to compress it a bit more using webp, this could save you some. I'd also serve it from the same domain as your website, instead of a different one. Reason is that currently a connection needs to be open just for this asset, while it could use an already open connection that is used for other assets.

Also, it seems that the other images in the body are loading before your loader image. This again slows down when the loader starts downloading. I suggest you leverage the lazy loading mechanics as much as possible: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading

Also, if you wanted to make sure the image is loaded ultra fast, you can incorporate its data directly in the html. You can get a Data URL that would be put in the src attribute, that URL contains all the image's details directly so it won't need to download. Actually, it WILL have to download but it will be in the HTML so the HTML size will be way bigger, longer to download but the image will be ready to display. See this image to get the data URL of the image in your developer drawer:
[image]

IMO, you are attacking it by the wrong angle. You are trying it add a loading animation to make the user wait while the website loads, but the website loads so fast that the loading animation is the one slowing it down. I'd really suggest removing it and optimizing the first draw instead.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was very informative and useful. If you are interested l24.im/8xFueW You can look at this issue. @Salketer